# How to mobilize drupal 6 site using module, keep theme for desktop viewing

Tags: mobile, drupal-6

I know, we are still on Drupal 6

I am wondering if there is an easy Module I can use to "Mobilize" our site?

I tried Modernizr, but it isn't happy.

We need to keep our current theme the way it is for desktop viewing, we just need to update tablet and phone viewing theme.

Has anyone had any luck using a module for Drupal 6 ?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

We are still on Drupal 6, too. I've found very little in the way of mobile or responsive themes for Drupal 6, since D7 was released when responsive became popular, so D6 has been left behind by most theme developers.

In the end my solution was to add responsive code to an existing theme. There was not a great deal of code involved in my case, but there is plenty you'll likely need to learn about how to do responsive design. And a lot will depend on your current theme, and whether its structure is compatible with common responsive approaches.

All that is to say, I found it ultimately more efficient to do the coding changes myself rather than adapt a third-party solution (modules or even existing responsive themes for D6).

Comment: Is the risk high in upgrading to Drupal 7 ?

Comment: In our case, our site was so big and had so many custom modules that the cost/time of upgrading to D7 was prohibitive. There are some major differences from D6 to D7. If your site uses mostly public modules, it might be worth upgrading to D7, but it's a major step that shouldn't be taken lightly.